calendar API no longer works after update
So far I have been able to create entries in Synology Calendar via API.
https://global.synologydownload.com/download/Document/Software/DeveloperGuide/Package/Calendar/2.4/enu/Synology_Calendar_API_Guide_enu.pdf
Since the update to version 2.5.0-21145, I get the error code for the entry via API:
9009
Unfortunately the developer documentation is not up to date.
Any ideas?
